# Is there a command to enter Visual Block mode?

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, user-commands, visual-block

I've set up a bunch of key mappings that would cause many Vim users to cringe. Now I am unable to get into Visual Block mode using Ctrl-V (Ctrl-Q isn't mapped, but it doesn't work).

Is there any command that I can type to enter Visual Block mode?

Ideally I could set something up so that `:vb` would enter visual block mode.

Comment: Sidenote: `<C-q>` is  the terminal "start" signal; Vim never sees it. Use `stty start undef` to disable it so that Vim sees it. You probably also want to disable the "stop" signal (`<C-s>`) with `stty stop undef`.

Comment: added the `stty start undef` to my .bashrc and it's working. I can use CTRL-Q for Visual Block now when vim is running in an terminal

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no built in command to start visual block mode in vim, but you can define one yourself:

```
command! Vb normal! <C-v>
```

Here is a breakdown of how it works:

- `command! Vb` - This creates a command called "Vb".  The `!` after `command` means that vim will not throw an error if the command is already defined.
- `normal! <C-v>` - This command tells vim to take all characters after it and act like you had pressed them in normal mode.  The `!` makes it so that all user defined mappings are ignored.  This means that if `<C-v>` is mapped to something else, it will still work the way it does by default.

Here are some relevant help topics:

- `:help :command`
- `:help :normal`

### NOTE

User defined commands must start with a capital letter.

Also, there may be a conflicting mapping which prevents you from using `<C-v>` to enter visual block mode.  To check for any conflicting mappings for `<C-v>`, you can run `:verbose map <C-v>`.

Comment: Then what would the command `gv` looks like using your answer?

Answer (score 10):

As far as I can find, there is no built-in command to start visual mode.

However, you can easily add these commands to Vim:

```
:command! Visual      normal! v
:command! VisualLine  normal! V
:command! VisualBlock execute "normal! \<C-v>"
```

You can change the names of these commands to whatever you want, but all user-defined commands *must* start with an upper-case letter (so you can't use `:vb`, but `:Vb` is okay).

Comment: You're the man. I was thinking that if I used `<C-v>` in a command, it would just call what I had remapped it to. Is that what the `normal!` is for?

Comment: Yes, the `!` added to `normal` bypasses user defined mappings.