# How to change editor mode from lua (or viml)

Tags: neovim

I know I can *get* the current mode, via `mode()`, but is it possible to *set* the current mode from viml or preferably lua (though I know a vim command/fn can be gotten to via the lua bridge).

I know I can `(nvim_)feedkeys(<mode>)`, but it feels like it's kind of a backwards way, faking input to alter state. `:insert` is for inserting lines, `:normal` runs commands in normal mode, but doesn't actually change the editor mode.

Is there really no `win_set_mode('n')` or similar? `feedkeys` is the correct method?

Edit per comment:

Specifically *right now, today, this moment*, I want to call `nvim_set_current_window(win_nr)` and then enter insert or normal mode in that window depending on other contexts.

I can do:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_current_win(ui_windows.editor.win)
local keys = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes("<ESC>", true, false, true)
vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(keys, "i", true)
```

but I'd much rather:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_current_win(ui_windows.editor.win)
vim.api.nvim_set_mode('i') -- or vim.fn.some_vim_mode_fn('i')
```

if it exists.

But I've had the same class of issue when writing vimscript and wanting to toggle mode.

Comment: Sounds like XY problem to me. If you run VimL you've already got into that mode somehow. It would be better if you explain what's you real point.

Comment: See edit. (character length requirement.)

Comment: Not if you switch to the window *while* in insert mode (via `imap ... <Cmd>...`) since <Cmd> can run without changing the mode of whatever context it's running in. I *could* put `<esc>` in the imap but I wanted to know if the described functionality existed. `:startinsert`/`:stopinsert`/`vim.cmd('startinsert')` is probably as close as it gets if you want to put it as an answer..

Comment: PS Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: It looks like some mode changes are easier than others. `startinsert` is also mentioned [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/257/automatically-load-vi-into-insert-mode) but a command to change to other modes [appears](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3699/is-there-a-command-to-enter-visual-block-mode) to not exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some conversation with the OP, we settled on

> `:startinsert`/`:stopinsert`/`vim.cmd('startinsert')` is probably as close as it gets